# Microservices communication in ASP.NET CORE Web API with RabbitMQ (AMPQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement microservice with asp .net core web API and doing R&D about RabbitMQ to communication with each web service.

about my project,It'a learning management system.When teacher need to send bulk email for class student. learning service api will send email list to email service and scribe for result.

[image]

I have searched about RabbitMQ sample and implement some class for create connection. But to do the asynchronize possess I think it should initialize in **Startup.cs** .But I couldn't find any samples for it stuck in that point for 2 days.
Check my code below and give me some help..

```js
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RabbitMQSender.RabbitMQ
{
    public class RabbitMQConnection
    {
        private static ConnectionFactory _factory;
        private static IConnection _connection;
        private static IModel _channel;

        public void CreateConnection()
        {
            _factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", UserName = "guest", Password = "guest" };
           // _factory = new ConnectionFactory(){HostName = "172.22.144.236",Port = 5672,UserName = "guest",Password = "guest"};
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

        public void ProcessMessages()
        {           

            using (_connection = _factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (_channel = _connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "msgKey", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                        var command = new AddUser{
                            FirstName = "Isanka",
                            LastName = "Thalagala",
                            EmailAddress = "isanka.thalagala@gmail.com",
                            Password = "examplePassword"
                        };
                    string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    _channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",routingKey: "msgKey",basicProperties: null,body: body);
                   
                   
                   
                }
            }
        }
  
      
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many examples about RabbitMQ in c#. But if you are going to implement asp.net core and if service needs to run automatically when api starts still can't find simple samples

Need to make statup.cs like this.

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQReiverCoreAPI.RebbitMQ;

namespace RabbitMQReiverCoreAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


            services.AddSingleton<RabbitMQPersistentConnection>(sp =>
            {
                var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RabbitMQPersistentConnection>>();

                var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
                {
                    HostName = Configuration["EventBusConnection"]
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration["EventBusUserName"]))
                {
                    factory.UserName = Configuration["EventBusUserName"];
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration["EventBusPassword"]))
                {
                    factory.Password = Configuration["EventBusPassword"];
                }

                return new RabbitMQPersistentConnection(factory);
            });

            services.AddOptions();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();

            //Initilize Rabbit Listener in ApplicationBuilderExtentions
            app.UseRabbitListener();
        }
    }
  
    public static class ApplicationBuilderExtentions
    {
        public static RabbitMQPersistentConnection Listener { get; set; }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseRabbitListener(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            Listener = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RabbitMQPersistentConnection>();
            var life = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();
            life.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);

            //press Ctrl+C to reproduce if your app runs in Kestrel as a console app
            life.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
            return app;
        }

        private static void OnStarted()
        {
            Listener.CreateConsumerChannel();
        }

        private static void OnStopping()
        {
            Listener.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

This is very simple way to implement RabbitMQ with asp .net core web API. Distributed messages handled by built in RabbitMQ implementation.

This source code as sample and you can improve with advance functionalities
Sample console sender and Asp.net core API receiver full project [here](https://github.com/isanka88/Send-and-Receive-Data-in-Asp.net-Core-With-RabbitMQ)